# Discord.js - Muting the bot itself when it joins a voice channel

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I want to be able to have the bot join a channel and server mute itself, and then when I want it to leave later, it should unmute itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first, you need to get your bot guid member, for this do `yourVoiceChannel.guild.me`, then, you need to mute him, for this is great function `guildMember.edit({mute:false/true})`. So you need to put this line to place of the code where the bot will join the voice channel: `voiceChannel.guild.me.edit({mute:true})`. And this line where he leaves: `voiceChannel.guild.me.edit({mute:false})`. This will have one problem, when the bot will restart, he can be still muted, to solve this put this line of code into ready event: `client.guilds.cache.each(guild => guild.me.edit({mute:false}))`. Also, it will be good idea to check, if the bot has permission to servermute, or use `guild.me.voice.setMute(false/true)`.

Comment: Thanks :) Works like a dream for discord.js V12 (anyone coming here in the future)